# How do I do event handing for drag-and-drop items?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, event-handling

I am building a WebApp with items to be dragged in place.

Once in place, I want to go to the next page.

How do I say "if item is in the coordinates, go to page2.html" else do nothing?

This is a WebApp, so HTML, HTML5, jQuery, javascript...TOUCH CAPABILITY IS A MUST...no native iOS/Android/Windows code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the catch place droppable, then perform function when dropped.

```
 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
         // do something here
     }
 });
```

Here's a quickie that should be self explanatory, hopefully!

```
<style>
.box1, .box2, .box3 { 
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin:30px;
background-color:#ccc;
padding:12px;
text-align:center;
}

.box2, .box3 {
height: 100px;
width: 100px; 
background-color: #f1f1f1;
border: 1px solid green;
cursor: pointer
}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var thisState = $(this).attr('oneDrop');
            if(thisState==='true'){
                alert('dragged and dropped now closed');
                $(this).droppable('destroy').html('closed now').css('background-color','red');
            }

        }
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<div class="droppable box1" onedrop="true">Box 1 - Drop in here</div>
<div class="box2 draggable">Box 2 - Drag me and drop me in Box 1</div>
<div class="box3 draggable">Box 3 - Drag me and try drop me in Box 1 after you've dragged Box 2 in there</div>
</body>
```

Drag box 2 into box 1, then box 1 stops becoming droppable. Therefore you can't drop box 3 into box 1 now as its essentially closed.

Hope this helps.

[Here's a fiddle to show what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/v95uX/)

Comment: So whats the start of the jQuery?...how do I declare that?

Comment: Udated answer, hopefully closer to what you need